# Snakemake input fastq files from each sample directory issue for metagenomics analysis

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, fastq

I am working on a new snakemake metagenomics pipeline to trim fastq files, and run them through kraken. Each sample has a directory containing the forward and reverse reads.

```
Sample_1/r1_paired.fq.gz
Sample_1/r2_paired.fq.gz
Sample_2/r1_paired.fq.gz
Sample_2/r2_paired.fq.gz
```

I am providing a sample sheet that users can upload, that contains the sample names and the read names. I used pandas to parse the sample sheet and provide the names required for the snakefile. Here is my snakefile.

```
 #Extract sample names from CSV
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv("sample_table_test.csv")
print(df)
samples = df.library.to_list()
print("Samples being processed:", samples)
R1 = df.r1_file.to_list()
R2 = df.r2_file.to_list()
print(R1,R2)


rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.bracken", sample=samples),
        

#Trimmomatic to trim paired end reads
rule trim_reads:
    input:
        "{sample}/{R1}",
        "{sample}/{R2}",
    output:
        "{sample}/{R1}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz",
        "{sample}/{R2}_2_trim_paired.fq.gz",
    conda:
        "env.yaml",
    shell:
        "trimmomatic PE -threads 8 {input} {input} {output} {output} SLIDINGWINDOW:4:30 LEADING:2 TRAILING:2 MINLEN:50"

#Kraken2 to bin reads and assign taxonomy
rule kraken2:
    input:
        "{sample}/{R1}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz",
        "{sample}/{R2}_2_trim_paired.fq.gz",
    output:
        "{sample}_report.txt",
        "{sample}_kraken_cseqs#.fq",
        
    conda:
        "env.yaml",
    shell:
        "kraken2 --gzip-compressed --paired --classified-out {output} {input} {input} --db database/minikraken2_v1_8GB/ --report {sample}_report.txt --threads 1"

#Bracken estimates abundance of a species within a sample
rule bracken:
    input:
        "{sample}_report.txt",
    output:
        "{sample}.bracken",
    conda:
        "env.yaml",
    shell:
        "bracken -d database/minikraken2_v1_8GB/ -i {input} -o {output} -r 150"
```

I am receiving the below error and have been struggling to find a better way to write my snakefile to avoid this issue. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

```
WildcardError in line 19 of /Metagenomics/Metagenomics/snakemake/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'R1'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `rule kraken2`:

```py
rule kraken2:
    input:
        "{sample}/{R1}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz",
        "{sample}/{R2}_2_trim_paired.fq.gz",
    output:
        "{sample}_report.txt",
        "{sample}_kraken_cseqs#.fq",
```

All wildcards in the rule shall be determined from the `output` section. The logic of each rule is that it offers certain files as a possible output. In your case the rule offers files `"{sample}_report.txt"` and `"{sample}_kraken_cseqs#.fq"`, where `{sample}` becomes one level of freedom and is substituted with a certain value that resolves the pattern into a filename. Now Snakemake can determine the inputs for this rule, but only if it has all the information. Ok, the value of `{sample}` is defined from the output, but what are the values of `{R1}` and `{R2}`?

You have several options. The first is to define these values somewhere in the `output:`. Looks like that is not your case. The second option is to define these values globally (as you are probably trying to do):

```py
R1 = df.r1_file.to_list()
R2 = df.r2_file.to_list()
```

In this case `{R1}` and `{R2}` shall not be wildcards but the parameters of the `expand` function:

```py
rule kraken2:
    input:
        expand("{{sample}}/{R1}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz", R1=R1),
        expand("{{sample}}/{R1}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz", R2=R2)
    output:
        "{sample}_report.txt",
        "{sample}_kraken_cseqs#.fq",
```

Or even better:

```py
expand("{{sample}}/{R}_1_trim_paired.fq.gz", R=R1+R2)
```

Note that the wildcard `{sample}` now has to be in double braces to be distinguished from the parameters of the `expand` function.

There are other options like resolving the value of `{R1}` from the values of other vildcards, like `lambda wildcards: ...`, but I guess that is not what you need.